# tab space replace with "-" with sed or tr

Tags: linux, bash, sed, tr

This is my file:
myfile.txt :

```
John Jony                                                   Old Boy
Maria                                                       Beautiful Girl
Dede YoYo                                                   Animal
```

with : `sed 's/ \+ /\ - /g' myfile.txt > ttt.txt`
I have this output :

```
John Jony - Old Boy -
Maria - Beautiful Girl -
Dede YoYo - Animal -
```

---

But I dont want to replace the second "tab" space.
I just take the first group and the second group with "space minus space (" - ") between. 
Thanks you!

Comment: Remove the `g`.

Comment: And if I have a dinamic content. I mean, sometime I have 3 or 4 col. with name and I want to put " - " after the last one and title ? For exanmle :
`John Jony       Another Name       Old Boy        `
And I want "John Jony & Another Name - Old Boy"

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more artists like

```
John Jony    Another Name    Old Boy
```

and want this output:

```
John Jony & Another Name - Old Boy
```

then it's a little more complicated, but not impossible for `awk`:

Input file:

```
John Jony    Another Name     Old Boy  
First artist    Second artist    Third artist    Song  
Maria             Beautiful Girl  
Dede YoYo         Animal
```

Command:

```
awk -F '  +' '
NF==3 {
sub("  +"," - ");
print
}

NF>3 {
  for (i=1;i<=NF-3;i++) {
    printf("%s",$i);
    printf(" & ");
  }
  printf("%s - %s\n",$(i++),$i);
}' myfile.txt > ttt.txt
```

**Output:**

```
John Jony & Another Name - Old Boy
First artist & Second artist & Third artist - Song
Maria - Beautiful Girl  
Dede YoYo - Animal
```

Comment: Who knows ... knows! people like me can only learn, big thanks them and make a reverence :-). 
Works perfect!
Thanks Mike!